# jQuery trigger() with keydown/up event on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3xVt/1/) - uses console.log().

```js
window.evtqueue = [];

window.eventHold = function(e){
    console.log(e.held);
    if (typeof(e.held)==typeof(undefined)){
        e.held = 1;
        window.evtqueue.push(e);

        console.log(e.type+" - "+e.which);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Triggering: "+e.type+" = "+e.which);
            var evt = window.evtqueue.splice(0,1)[0];
            $('#edittext').trigger(evt);
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("Event actually triggered!");
    }
}

$('#edittext').on('keydown keyup', window.eventHold)
```

I'm making a rich text editor, and was having some issues with quick keystrokes vs. asynchronous code (which is out of my control), so, I decided to make an event queue. However, I'm having trouble getting saved events to fire with `.trigger()`, and when I can manage that, they don't seem to fire their defaults.

What am I missing? Does this require more events to be bound to actually trigger the defaults, like `keypress`? Is it failing because the original bound event thing returns false, despite this being asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because you returned false before you trigger the event

If you return false, the

```
event.isPropagationStopped() and event.isDefaultPrevented() is true
```

The source code show, if both of them is true, the trigger method will do nothing

Comment: I see - so is it possible to save an event for use later, without it firing the first time? It doesn't seem to work if I just set isDefaultPrevented and isPropagationStopped to function(){return false;}

Comment: really? http://jsfiddle.net/85xXe/
I just set the isPropagationStopped proprety, and it worked

Comment: The default still isn't happening for me, is it working for you? The event is firing though.

Comment: The trigger is belong to jQuery, It just call the function you add in for the event callback, so if you want to trigger the default, I think you can use string.fromCharCode(e.which) to restore, but I test it can just get the big letter.